# OpenERP IOError: decoder zip not available

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, odoo

I have installed openERP 7 multiple times on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine.
I am unable to create new user in openERP 7. When i try to create new user it shows message

> IOError: decoder zip not available

Unable to post complete output of the Error message.

I have already installed all required python packages. But have not solved it yet.

Comment: Just solved this issue removed from system PIL which was causing conflict using pip uninstall PIL and its working now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by uninstalling PIL but it's a bit like preventing fillings by pulling out your teeth; you solve the immediate problem but...

The IOError you are seeing is usually because PIL can't handle jpeg images.  This happens because PIL is using hard-coded library paths.

To fix (on Ubuntu 12.04)

1. pip uninstall PIL
2. sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
3. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
4. pip install PIL

Note the output at the end of the PIL install, it will tell you which image types it is now handling.

Answer (score 0):

i use openerp 7 with ubuntu 13.10.

try this:

1. remove python-image
2. locate your libz
3. reinstall PIL

see in detail here : http://febru.soluvas.com/2014/03/solved-openerp-7-ioerror-decoder-zip.html